# C++ Libraries to parsing

Tags: c++, parsing, interpreter, bison, boost-spirit

I'm doing a software to generate animations for algorithms. These algorithms are written in an interpreted language, near to C (more or less a C-oriented pseudocode). Thus, my program must interprets algorithms written in these language. Also, this language will be incremented all the time to support more and more features. The key issue here is to search an library allowing increase the language easily and making easy integrate different parsers in the same program. The app is written in C++ licensed under GPL.

A object-oriented parser is my target solution indeed. I need help to choose a good library with this purposes. Also it's desirable the library is multiplataform and available in official repositories of commons distributions: Ubuntu, Suse and so on.

Actually, I know more or less well the next two libraries/tools:

- Flex/Bison++: Both are Flex/Bison wrappers that allow generate C++ code instead of C code, and choose a name for your class. Problems: if you install Flex/Bison++, Flex/Bison are overwritten. I don't want to complicate users if they want compile my code. Moreover, CMake fails search the version number of the library. This can be solved manually, but isn't elegant.
- Boost.Spirit: It doesn't have the previous problems and match with all desirable features I described above. But, I've read it isn't fine to parse big languages and to solve grammar ambiguities. Moreover, the compilation times are enormous. But, I love it can compose grammars in a constructive manner. This is very important to make the code/language/programm extensible.

What is your recommendation?

Comment: Please read [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on what questions are generally considered a good fit for SO.

Comment: What is wrong in my question? I ask about "software tools commonly used by programmers" and answerable. An expert in parsers, viewing my description, can answer me about libraries this expert knows and its adventages in relation to my problem.

Comment: It is a question solliciting subjective opinions, and or lists of possible tools. In fact your question matches more than 1 explicitely listed examples in the [Don't ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) section (_do click_ 'show more'!)

Comment: Ok. I agree with deleting this question if it's necessary.

Comment: Whether you delete the question or not is up to you but look into GOLD parser builder and see if it will fit your needs.